# How to add firebase to flutter application

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'Header1.dart';
import 'InputWrapper1.dart';

class LoginPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset : false,
      body: Container(
        width: double.infinity,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          gradient: LinearGradient(begin: Alignment.topCenter, colors: [
            Colors.blue[500],
            Colors.purple[300],
            Colors.purple[400]
          ]),
        ),
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            SizedBox(height: 80,),
            Header1(),
            Expanded(child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                    topLeft: Radius.circular(60),
                    topRight: Radius.circular(60),
                  )
              ),
              child: InputWrapper1(),
            ))

          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  } 
}
```

I want to add firebase to this login and signup page but i am confused saw many video they were adding function to login but over here every element is divided in multiple section where to add?
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mkh7W.jpg
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zqPYE.jpg

Comment: you can start by putting some code in your question , that will be helpful , like what you have tried so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should keep the UI separated from your login logic and everything else regarding data management. Use the [provider package](https://pub.dev/packages/provider) and set up a login provider that handles your login logic behind the scenes, for example. I recommend watching [this video](https://youtu.be/d_m5csmrf7I) to learn more about proper state management.

Once you set up the login provider, you can access login functionality from everywhere in your source code. Firebase authentication in Flutter works best when using the [Firebase authentication package](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_auth). Just in case you didn‘t use it already :)

Comment: Hi Nicolas it worked for me thank you!!!

Comment: @OMKARKOMARPANT Glad I could help!